# Laravel File::exists() always false

Tags: php, laravel-4

okay, this is stupid: what am I doing wrong? This is always returning false, even when I've tested the path manually.

```
dd(File::exists('/uploads/photo.jpg'));
```

I've also tried it with the absolute path ('http://example.com/uploads.photo.jpg')

In all instances, I'm getting a `false` return, even when I've tested the file directly.

Comment: http://example.com/uploads/... is not an **absolute local path**

Comment: okay, but when I use `http://example.com/uploads.photo.jpg` it still doesn't work.

Comment: No that is not what I meant, try to use something similar to this: `/var/www/mysite/uploads/photo.jpg`

Comment: ah, gotcha. will try. thnks

Comment: @d3l - that worked; thanks. add an answer and i'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example.com/uploads... is not an **absolute local path**, instead try something similar to this:

`/var/www/mysite/uploads/photo.jpg`